# Isn't the timeline for weekly photo contest strictly followed?

Tags: discussion, featured-photo, contest

Is it like the timeline of the contest is not being strictly followed any more? The image on the site header was chosen on June 6. It was supposed to be there until June 13 when it had to be replaced with the image for the next week. I can't see the winning images on June 13 and June 20.

When is the result announced?

What is the range of dates considered for photo submission for a given contest?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know that it's ever been strictly updated.  I try to update every 10-14 days.  It is called the weekly featured image, so I will make an effort to be a bit more consistent with it.  It's not a big job, it's just a matter of remembering to do it.

There is no range of dates considered, it's cumulative votes over the lifetime of the contest.  There has been talk of restarting it periodically.

Comment: No offense. But, if you simply pick up a photo with highest vote from the visible ones (I don't think you flip through hundreds of photos posted so far), it's not a weekly contest any more. That itself reduces people's attraction towards the contest. I think it'd be better write a script using StackExchange API which runs on Sunday 11:59:59 to choose the image with maximum votes among the ones posted from last Monday 00:00:00 to Sunday 11:59:5, posts the chosen photo on hall of fame thread and updates the header (preferably).

Comment: It's the weekly featured image (changing weekly) and it's an "ongoing" format, which is something the community decided to do, rather than creating a new question/thread every week : http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2646/idea-change-pic-of-week-contest-to-continuously-rolling-voting

Comment: I wonder how you choose the top-voted entry. I can't seem to find the latest winner among the ones within the second page of the thread.

Comment: We sort the page by votes, choose the top-voted entry, then delete the entry.

Comment: I see. Nice trick.

Comment: To see and vote on the latest entries, choose the [active tab for that question](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2657/?answertab=active#tab-top)